# Receiving error The model migrationhistory from the app south is not available in this migration in django

Tags: django, django-south, django-orm

I am receiving the error that I can't get get the migration history object:

```
The model migrationhistory from the app south is not available in this migration
```

I do this when I try to do the following in my data migration:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
        migration = orm['south.MigrationHistory'].objects.all()
```

Why can't I do this to remove an erroneous row i have in my south history table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help @lalo

You need to freeze the south model like so:

```
python manage.py datamigration appname remove_migration --freeze south
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, see this [docs](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ormfreezing.html#accessing-the-orm)

You should create the datamigration with:

```
./manager datamigration myapp datamigration_name --freeze south
```

Replace 'myapp' with you current migrated app

**EDIT**

Sorry, I thought it's a schemamigration, without --auto, but with --freeze. And add the datamigration name. my apologies

Comment: it says: no such option -auto ?  Do i just omit that?